# do flurry analytics distinguish by user, or give overall analytics?

Tags: flurry

Couldn't find this in the faq. Does Flurry give analytics that distinguish users? So I can see that this user did some actions, and another user did some other actions..or does flurry just give overall analytics (all users did a total of these number of events)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flurry by itself does not distinguish your users in a way you can track yourself. They do keep track of them behind the scenes to determine which users are new or returning, and which ones are linked to your other apps, but will not give you any specific info on them.

They do have a unique id they allow you to set if you wish to track them yourself. Hope this helps.